# Verification of Google Search Console via Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-search-console

I have a problem with verification website in Google Search Console via Google Tag Manager. I have a site on Wordpress and GTM installed via GTM4WP plugin. Noscript part was set up to "Codeless injection (no tweak, right placement but experimental, could break your frontend)" in plugin settings.

When I am trying to verify it by GTM it returned error : *"We could not find a Google Tag Manager container ID on the home page of your site."*

When I am trying Google Analytics method it returned *"We could not find any Google Analytics tracking codes on the index page of your site." error.*

To be clear - GTM and GA works quite well. It collects data for almost 2 years. What am I doing wrong?

//Edit

Here is how code looks like in head section. It is located on 677 row while  marks is on 697.

[image]

But I see that the noscript that should be in body section is not in the code. But why? I configure everything via GTM4WP plugin like below. Should I switch to Custom & PHP option?:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check if the position of GTM code is exactly the same indicated by GTM guidelines.
Concerning the error on Google Analytics it is returned to you because probably you haven't the GA snippet on the page because you deliver it by GTM.

Guidelines said to put noscript part in body because this part could be useful if JavaScript in user browser is disabled.

Comment: I add "//edit" to the post.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you're a WordPress user have you considering using [Site Kit by Google](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) to insert your Google Tag Manager snippet? In additional Tag Manger it can auto verify your site on Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that noscript code didn't show up on source code no matter how it was implemented by plugin. But developer add it manually and verification on GSC was successful after that change.